# LNK1112: module machine type 'IA64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

This error appears when I try to include libc.lib in my project and, even though my Windows is 32 bits, I have this error. Don't know if I have to download it from somewhere or what.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link a library that is compiled for the IA64 architecture. That's 64 bit Itanium. You've somehow got the wrong version of the library. You'll need to find the x86 version.